# What's wrong with my EXECUTE command?

Tags: sql, procedure, mysql-error-1064, execute, heidisql

I'm trying to make a `PROCEDURE` that makes it easier to store changes users make in their settings (like a server log, you know right) into a table `user_settings_changelog`. I finally made the `PROCEDURE` acceptable so my sql program (HeidiSQL) would store it. Now the problem is this: how to properly `EXECUTE` it. I tried this multiple times with multiple lines of code, but it seemed nothing worked. Can anyone help me out here?

The `PROCEDURE` query:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE setting_adjustment_log (name_setting VARCHAR(45), 
changed_from VARCHAR(45), changed_to VARCHAR(45), username 
VARCHAR(45))
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO user_settings_changelog
    VALUES (GETDATE(), name_setting, changed_from, changed_to, 
username);
END$$
```

The table `user_settings_changelog` has 5 columns: date `DATETIME`, name_setting `VARCHAR(45)`, changed_from `VARCHAR(45)`, changed_to `VARCHAR(45)` and username `VARCHAR(45)`.

The `EXECUTE` query:

```
EXECUTE setting_adjustment_log ('background','black','white','TheCoderNoob');
```

The error HeidiSQL gives me:

SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '('background','black','white','TheCoderNoob')' at line 1

Maybe useful to mention: I am using a version of USBwebserver from a few years ago.

EDIT: I've been looking at the `EXECUTE`/`CALL` query in MySQL Workbench for a while, it seems like the database expects something between the name of the procedure and the given data or something. When I hover over it, it reads:

Syntax error: 'background' (single quoted text) is not a valid input at this position

Comment: Remove the opening parens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should always include the column names in an `insert` statement.  (There might be a few exceptions, but if you are learning SQL, then sticks with best practices.)

Second, distinguish the input parameters from possible column names.

Third, your code looks like MySQL, so use `NOW()` or a similar function:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE setting_adjustment_log (
    in_name_setting VARCHAR(45), 
    in_changed_from VARCHAR(45),
    in_changed_to VARCHAR(45),
    in_username VARCHAR(45)
)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO user_settings_changelog (date, name_setting, changed_from, changed_to, username)
    VALUES (NOW(), in_name_setting, in_changed_from, in_changed_to, 
in_username);
END$$
```

When you call the stored procedure, use `call`:

```
CALL setting_adjustment_log('background', 'black', 'white', 'TheCoderNoob');
```

Comment: Firstly, thanks a lot for the quick response. However,  the error code now looks like this: SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''background', 'black', 'white', 'TheCoderNoob'' at line 1

Comment: And yes, the code is practically MySQL. The USBwebserver provides a regular MySQL server, HeidiSQL is just a program to use the server, as far as I know.

Comment: @TheCoderNoob . . . That is because you want `call`, not `execute`.

Comment: Nope, with `CALL` and `EXECUTE` i have exactly the same problem. Note: I edited the question a bit

Comment: THANKS A LOT!! `CALL` does only work with brackets, although `EXECUTE` doesn't work at all for me... Well, at least its solved :).